# Climbing wall on private home

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing, diy

I'm just curious how feasible it is to install a rock climbing wall on the side of a regular, balloon framed house (modern standard in the U.S. and Canada). Would something like that require constructing a special support structure? Assuming you tear down whatever siding you may have where you want the wall to be.

Comment: A freestanding bouldering wall might be more bang for your buck and less of a hassle to build.

Comment: @strongbad, I built a scissors truss freestanding bouldering wall a few years ago, building a wall onto an existing structure is a lot easier in my experience, because you don't have to build the foundation or frame a support structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very feasible, I know of a couple houses that have a climbing wall on one side, but you'd be better off leaving the siding up, your wall is going to have bolt holes in it which will let in water. You won't need a special support structure, your exterior walls should be framed with 2x6's if it's less than 30 years old, you just need to attach some boards flat against the side of your house to attach your plywood to. Paint it with an exterior paint mixed with a bit of sand, and you're pretty much good to go. Whatever you do, I would at least consult a contractor if not hire one to build it for you.